# Weird behaviour of Perl references

Tags: perl, oop

Have a look at this piece of code:

```
my @arr = (1, 2);
my $ref = \@arr;
my @s = @$ref;
push @s, 4;
print join(", ", @arr) . "\n";
```

Unexpectedly, the output is "1, 2". What happened? How come I got two different arrays (@s  is (1,2,4))?

Of course I get "1, 2, 4" if I write, before the output, something like this:

```
$ref = \@s;
@arr = @$ref;
```

But that seems rather clumsy.

I'm used to other OOP languages, in which such a thing wouldn't happen - an object can me modified, regardless of its references.

So can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @s = @$ref;
```

makes a *copy* of the referenced array.  After that, `@s` and `@arr` are unrelated arrays that just happen to have the same contents (for a while).

If you want to modify the referenced array, you have to use it directly, e.g.:

```
push @$ref, 4;
```

There's also the [Data::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aAlias) module, which (I think) lets you do what you're asking for.  But there's deep magic involved there, and I've never used it myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's quite bizarre, no? Is there any way to "fix" it? My intention is as follows: I have a class, which one of its fields is a reference to an array. I wish to change that array in a different class, so I did @array = @{$object->{array}}; and that didn't work. So you're saying the best way to do it is to write my $ref = $object->{array} and do push @$ref every time?

Comment: @Rob, that's one way to do it.  In Perl 5.14, you can write `push $ref, 4` instead (implicit dereferencing).  You could also write a `push_array` method, and then do `$object->push_array(4)`.  [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native) can help simplify that.